# how to remove js files from layout added to page through require or direct src

Tags: javascript, magento2.4.6, optimization

i want to remove js files from a layout

> checkout_index_index

which is loading by require or direct src.

1)

```
<script src="https://abc.abc.ai/prompt.js" src_type="url" />
```

this file is loading in checkout file  but when i try to remove it, doesnt work with this code

Comment: hello dear, can you install any third-party extension.? Because if you installed a third-party extension that is required. so you can't delete it.

Comment: Is the mentioned JS file added to the checkout_index_index layout? Can you please tell us where this JS is defined?

Comment: yes file added to checkout_index_index

Answer (score 0):

**You can overwrite the layout file in the theme or custom module and add the following code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="https://abc.abc.ai/prompt.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: it wont work thanks for your reply

Comment: Have you run the static content deployment command and checked it?

Comment: yes brother, already tried.